# Route handling a uniquely generated URL specific to a user in ReactJS and react-router-dom v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In the app I am working on if a user forgot their password, they click on a link that brings them to a page where they enter the username. If the username is matched, it sends a uniquely generated URL to the email associated with the username. For example:

```
http://localhost:8000/auth/security_questions/0e51706361e7a74a550e995b415409fdab4c66f0d201c25cb4fa578959d11ffa
```

All of this works fine, but I am trying to figure out how to handle this on the front-end routing using `React` and `react-router-dom v4`. I made this route.

```
<Route exact path='/auth/security_questions/:key' component={SecurityQuestions} />
```

The correct component loads related to security questions, but that is not the behavior I am after. After all, it takes anything you put after `security_questions/`.

What it should be doing is matching `:key` against the database before it loads the component.

I'm not sure about a few things:

1) How to parse out the `:key` portion so that I can pass it as a value to verify against the database.

2) While I have a general idea of how to handle the verification, I am not sure how to tell `React`: "Ok, the key has been verified in the database. Finish loading the component."

I think it would in general look like:

```
// ./containers/security_questions.js

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.verifyKey(:key);
}
```

And then actions:

```
// ./actions/authentication.index.js

export function verifyKey({ :key }) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios
            .post(
                `${ROOT_URL}/api/auth/security_questions/`, 
                { :key }
            )
            .then(response => {

                dispatch('Finish loading the rest of the component')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(authError(error.response.data.non_field_errors[0]));
            });
    }
}
```

Or maybe instead of it finishing loading the component, it should just route to a different URL that is a protected route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can grab the params from the path like so (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route):

   ```
   <Route path="/user/:username" component={User}/>

   const User = ({ match }) => <h1>Hello {match.params.username}!</h1>
   ```
2. You will want to conditionally render based upon some state set by verifyKey.

   ```
   componentWillMount() {
     this.props.verifyKey(this.props.match.params.key);
   }

   render() {
     if (this.state.permitRender) {
       return <Component>
     } else {
       return <LoadingComponent />
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the render method on the route to put in your verification logic and render the appropriate control. You would need to move the action to verify the key to the component which renders the route, rather than the SecurityQuestions component.

```
<Route exact 
    path='/auth/security_questions/:key' 
    render={(props)=>{
         let finalComponent= <ComponentToRenderWhenKeyDoesNotMatch/>;
         if(this.props.verifyKey(props.match.params.key)){
              resultantComponent=<SecurityQuestions/>
         }
         return finalComponent;
     }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Route params will be inside the `match.params` prop:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.verifyKey(this.props.match.params.key);
}
```

See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

--

Then on the success of your security questions I would set some state in your reducer and render based on that.